# How to select min month and year?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, min

I've got a table like this:

```
cuota_abono(**cod_abono**, **mes**, **anio**, valor, pago_acumulado, estado)

where:
-cod_abono: VARCHAR (PK)  
-mes: INT (month -- values from 1 to 12) (PK)  
-anio: INT (year) (PK)  
-valor: DECIMAL(10,2)  
-pago_acumulado: DECIMAL(10,2)  
-estado(TINYINT -- 0 or 1)
```

The thing is that I need to select the oldest not-payed cuota_abono (where estado=0).

For instance:

```
cod_abono mes   anio     valor  pago_acumulado  estado
  Z000     9    2015    315.00      100.00         0
  Z000     5    2016    315.00      315.00         1
  Z000     6    2016    315.00      200.00         0
  Z000     7    2016    315.00        0.00         0
  Z001     5    2016    315.00        0.00         0
  Z001     6    2016    315.00      315.00         1
```

Given that I'm looking for the oldest cuota_abono, I'm looking to get:

```
(Z000, 9, 2015, 315.00, 100.00, 0) --> 1° row
```

I tried with this query:

```
select cod_abono, min(mes), min(anio), valor, pago_acumulado, estado
from cuota_abono 
where cod_abono="Z000" and cuota_paga=0
```

However, I get:

```
(Z000, *6*, 2015, 315.00, 100.00, 0)
```

I actually get the minimum month where cod_abono="Z000" and estado=0, numerically speaking, but it's not correct.

Any suggestions?

Comment: tag only one dbms you are actually using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `order by` and `limit`:

```
select ca.*
from cuota_abono ca
where cod_abono = 'Z000' and cuota_paga = 0
order by anio, mes
limit 1;
```

Comment: Yes, I had just realized about this option. Thanks!